# Send array from js to php to SQL database

Tags: php, jquery, sql

I hope I'm missing something easy here.

I have an array created in js, say: `var ids = [1,2,3,4,5];`

Now I want this array to populate a column in my SQL database table.

I have the pipeline setup for adding single elements to my table like this:

1. request is sent via ajax:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "some.php",
  data: {
    ids: ids,
  }
});
```

2. `some.php` receives the data (connection, etc. is set up):

`$ids = $_POST['ids'];`

3. SQL is used to insert single values to the column COL_ID

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `mydb`.`dbtable`(`COL_ID`) VALUES ('$ids)";
```

This pipeline works for single values (e.g. of `ids = 2` but fails for an array.

What I'd want is for `COL_ID` to contain each array element as a row

```
| COL_ID    |
|--------   |
| 1         |
| 2         |
| 3         |
| 4         |
| 5         |
```

I suspect it's in the SQL query. Any help is welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, use prepared statements, don't insert post data directly into a database query. Using post data directly means you are vulnerable to sql injection attacks.

As @DanielReed indicated, the correct format is

```
INSERT INTO table_name (column_list) VALUES (value_list_1), (value_list_2), (value_list_3);
```

You can build this dynamically:

```
$ids = $_POST['ids'];
// Make sure we get the correct number of ? for prepared statements
$params = str_repeat('(?), ', count($ids));
// Strip the trailing space and comma
$params = substr($params, 0, -2);

$sql = 'INSERT INTO `mydb`.`dbtable`(`COL_ID`) VALUES ' . $params;
```

Now you can use $sql as your query and $ids as the values for the prepared statement. This prevents sql injection.

Comment: Thanks. Sorry for the question: if I use `$sql` as my query in, say, `mysqli_query($con,$sql)`, where do I specify that it should use the $ids? Maybe I misunderstand what you mean by "use ... $ids as the values for the prepared statement".

Comment: You could use `mysqli_prepare($con, $sql);` and then `mysqli_stmt_bind_param(...)`. See the manual for examples: https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php

Comment: This is a better answer then mine. @ben_aaron You should always bind the value using what he said otherwise people can perform SQL injection attacks on you.

Answer (score 1):

PHP receives it as an array.

SQL Syntax wants it in the following syntax:

```
INSERT INTO table_name (column_list)
VALUES
    (value_list_1),
    (value_list_2),
    ...
    (value_list_n);
```

So what you could do is:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `mydb`.`dbtable`(`COL_ID`) ";
foreach($ids as $value){
     $sql .= "(".$value.") ";
}
```

Comment: Thanks. If I understand correctly, this creates multiple $sql (one in each run). Where would I make the query, e.g. with `mysqli_query($con,$sql)`?

Comment: Yeah so the .= means concatenate. It pretty much appends it to the end of the string. So if you were to say $str = "Hello";  $str .= " My name is";  $str .= " Daniel";   --- the value of $str would be "Hello My name is Daniel". So you would run the query the same as you mentioned in your comment. You may have to add a space after the parenthesis since it's going to just join them together, i'll edit my answer to add that.

Comment: Oh and they need commas after each one too, so my answer wont work without tweaking